# Installing eth-brownie error | ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl

Tags: solidity, tutorials

I am trying to install eth-brownie to follow the Patrick Collins Solidity Course however I can't get past this error I have been googling for a few days.

This is the error:

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for yarl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

This is the full report:

```
Collecting eth-brownie
  Using cached eth_brownie-1.19.2-py3-none-any.whl (232 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp==3.8.3 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (3.8.3)
Collecting aiosignal==1.2.0
  Using cached aiosignal-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting asttokens==2.0.5
  Using cached asttokens-2.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout==4.0.2 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (4.0.2)
Collecting attrs==22.1.0
  Using cached attrs-22.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: base58==2.1.1 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (2.1.1)
Collecting bitarray==2.6.0
  Using cached bitarray-2.6.0.tar.gz (102 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting black==22.10.0
  Using cached black-22.10.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting certifi==2022.9.24
  Using cached certifi-2022.9.24-py3-none-any.whl (161 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer==2.1.1 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click==8.1.3 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (8.1.3)
Collecting cytoolz==0.12.0
  Using cached cytoolz-0.12.0.tar.gz (502 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting dataclassy==0.11.1
  Using cached dataclassy-0.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting eip712==0.1.0
  Using cached eip712-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-abi==2.2.0 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-account==0.5.9 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (0.5.9)
Collecting eth-event==1.2.3
  Using cached eth_event-1.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (7.3 kB)
Collecting eth-hash[pycryptodome]==0.3.3
  Using cached eth_hash-0.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (8.9 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-keyfile==0.5.1 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-keys==0.3.4 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (0.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-rlp==0.2.1 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-typing==2.3.0 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (2.3.0)
Collecting eth-utils==1.10.0
  Using cached eth_utils-1.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting execnet==1.9.0
  Using cached execnet-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting frozenlist==1.3.1
  Using cached frozenlist-1.3.1.tar.gz (66 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting hexbytes==0.2.3
  Using cached hexbytes-0.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (6.4 kB)
Collecting hypothesis==6.27.3
  Using cached hypothesis-6.27.3-py3-none-any.whl (384 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: idna==3.4 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (3.4)
Collecting inflection==0.5.0
  Using cached inflection-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
Collecting iniconfig==1.1.1
  Using cached iniconfig-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.0 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: ipfshttpclient==0.8.0a2 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (0.8.0a2)
Collecting jsonschema==3.2.0
  Using cached jsonschema-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
Collecting lazy-object-proxy==1.7.1
  Using cached lazy-object-proxy-1.7.1.tar.gz (41 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: lru-dict==1.1.8 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (1.1.8)
Requirement already satisfied: multiaddr==0.0.9 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (0.0.9)
Collecting multidict==6.0.2
  Using cached multidict-6.0.2.tar.gz (50 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: mypy-extensions==0.4.3 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (0.4.3)
Collecting mythx-models==1.9.1
  Using cached mythx_models-1.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: netaddr==0.8.0 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (0.8.0)
Collecting packaging==21.3
  Using cached packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: parsimonious==0.8.1 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (0.8.1)
Collecting pathspec==0.10.1
  Using cached pathspec-0.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
Collecting platformdirs==2.5.2
  Using cached platformdirs-2.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting pluggy==1.0.0
  Using cached pluggy-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting prompt-toolkit==3.0.31
  Using cached prompt_toolkit-3.0.31-py3-none-any.whl (382 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf==3.19.5 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (3.19.5)
Collecting psutil==5.9.2
  Using cached psutil-5.9.2.tar.gz (479 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting py==1.11.0
  Using cached py-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
Collecting py-solc-ast==1.2.9
  Using cached py_solc_ast-1.2.9-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: py-solc-x==1.1.1 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (1.1.1)
Collecting pycryptodome==3.15.0
  Using cached pycryptodome-3.15.0-cp35-abi3-win_amd64.whl (1.9 MB)
Collecting pygments==2.13.0
  Using cached Pygments-2.13.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting pygments-lexer-solidity==0.7.0
  Using cached pygments_lexer_solidity-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyjwt==1.7.1
  Using cached PyJWT-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting pyparsing==3.0.9
  Using cached pyparsing-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
Collecting pyrsistent==0.18.1
  Using cached pyrsistent-0.18.1.tar.gz (100 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pytest==6.2.5
  Using cached pytest-6.2.5-py3-none-any.whl (280 kB)
Collecting pytest-forked==1.4.0
  Using cached pytest_forked-1.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
Collecting pytest-xdist==1.34.0
  Using cached pytest_xdist-1.34.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil==2.8.1
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Collecting python-dotenv==0.16.0
  Using cached python_dotenv-0.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting pythx==1.6.1
  Using cached pythx-1.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting pyyaml==5.4.1
  Using cached PyYAML-5.4.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: requests==2.28.1 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (2.28.1)
Requirement already satisfied: rlp==2.0.1 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: semantic-version==2.10.0 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six==1.16.0 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (1.16.0)
Collecting sortedcontainers==2.4.0
  Using cached sortedcontainers-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting toml==0.10.2
  Using cached toml-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting tomli==2.0.1
  Using cached tomli-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: toolz==0.12.0 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (0.12.0)
Collecting tqdm==4.64.1
  Using cached tqdm-4.64.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
Collecting urllib3==1.26.12
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: varint==1.0.2 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (1.0.2)
Collecting vvm==0.1.0
  Using cached vvm-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting eth-brownie
  Using cached eth_brownie-1.19.1-py3-none-any.whl (232 kB)
Collecting aiohttp==3.8.1
  Using cached aiohttp-3.8.1.tar.gz (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting black==22.6.0
  Using cached black-22.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
Collecting certifi==2022.6.15
  Using cached certifi-2022.6.15-py3-none-any.whl (160 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer==2.1.0
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting hexbytes==0.2.2
  Using cached hexbytes-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (6.1 kB)
Collecting idna==3.3
  Using cached idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting pathspec==0.9.0
  Using cached pathspec-0.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Collecting prompt-toolkit==3.0.30
  Using cached prompt_toolkit-3.0.30-py3-none-any.whl (381 kB)
Collecting protobuf==3.20.1
  Using cached protobuf-3.20.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (162 kB)
Collecting psutil==5.9.1
  Using cached psutil-5.9.1.tar.gz (479 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pygments==2.12.0
  Using cached Pygments-2.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting semantic-version==2.8.5
  Using cached semantic_version-2.8.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting tqdm==4.64.0
  Using cached tqdm-4.64.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
Collecting urllib3==1.26.11
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (139 kB)
Collecting eth-brownie
  Using cached eth_brownie-1.19.0-py3-none-any.whl (232 kB)
Collecting attrs==21.4.0
  Using cached attrs-21.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
Collecting bitarray==1.2.2
  Using cached bitarray-1.2.2.tar.gz (48 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting black==22.3.0
  Using cached black-22.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (153 kB)
Collecting certifi==2022.5.18.1
  Using cached certifi-2022.5.18.1-py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer==2.0.12
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting cytoolz==0.11.2
  Using cached cytoolz-0.11.2.tar.gz (481 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting eth-abi==2.1.1
  Using cached eth_abi-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
Collecting eth-account==0.5.7
  Using cached eth_account-0.5.7-py3-none-any.whl (101 kB)
Collecting eth-hash[pycryptodome]==0.3.2
  Using cached eth_hash-0.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (8.8 kB)
Collecting frozenlist==1.3.0
  Using cached frozenlist-1.3.0.tar.gz (65 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting lru-dict==1.1.7
  Using cached lru_dict-1.1.7-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
Collecting prompt-toolkit==3.0.29
  Using cached prompt_toolkit-3.0.29-py3-none-any.whl (381 kB)
Collecting pycryptodome==3.14.1
  Using cached pycryptodome-3.14.1-cp35-abi3-win_amd64.whl (1.8 MB)
Collecting requests==2.27.1
  Using cached requests-2.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
Collecting toolz==0.11.2
  Using cached toolz-0.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (55 kB)
Collecting urllib3==1.26.9
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting eth-brownie
  Using cached eth_brownie-1.18.2-py3-none-any.whl (230 kB)
Collecting certifi==2021.10.8
  Using cached certifi-2021.10.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (149 kB)
Collecting psutil==5.9.0
  Using cached psutil-5.9.0.tar.gz (478 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting eth-brownie
  Using cached eth_brownie-1.18.1-py3-none-any.whl (225 kB)
Collecting black==22.1.0
  Using cached black-22.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (160 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer==2.0.11
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.0.11-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting click==8.0.3
  Using cached click-8.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting platformdirs==2.4.1
  Using cached platformdirs-2.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting prompt-toolkit==3.0.26
  Using cached prompt_toolkit-3.0.26-py3-none-any.whl (375 kB)
Collecting protobuf==3.19.4
  Using cached protobuf-3.19.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (162 kB)
Collecting pygments==2.11.2
  Using cached Pygments-2.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting pyparsing==3.0.7
  Using cached pyparsing-3.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
Collecting tomli==2.0.0
  Using cached tomli-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting tqdm==4.62.3
  Using cached tqdm-4.62.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions==4.0.1
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting urllib3==1.26.8
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting eth-brownie
  Using cached eth_brownie-1.18.0-py3-none-any.whl (225 kB)
  Using cached eth_brownie-1.17.2-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
Collecting async-timeout==4.0.1
  Using cached async_timeout-4.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.7 kB)
Collecting asynctest==0.13.0
  Using cached asynctest-0.13.0-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting attrs==21.2.0
  Using cached attrs-21.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
Collecting black==21.11b1
  Using cached black-21.11b1-py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
Collecting cached-property==1.5.2
  Using cached cached_property-1.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer==2.0.9
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting eth-account==0.5.6
  Using cached eth_account-0.5.6-py3-none-any.whl (101 kB)
Collecting eth-keys==0.3.3
  Using cached eth_keys-0.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting eth-typing==2.2.2
  Using cached eth_typing-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (6.2 kB)
Collecting frozenlist==1.2.0
  Using cached frozenlist-1.2.0.tar.gz (65 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting importlib-metadata==4.8.2
  Using cached importlib_metadata-4.8.2-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting lazy-object-proxy==1.6.0
  Using cached lazy_object_proxy-1.6.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
Collecting multidict==5.2.0
  Using cached multidict-5.2.0.tar.gz (49 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting platformdirs==2.4.0
  Using cached platformdirs-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting prompt-toolkit==3.0.23
  Using cached prompt_toolkit-3.0.23-py3-none-any.whl (374 kB)
Collecting protobuf==3.19.1
  Using cached protobuf-3.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (162 kB)
Collecting psutil==5.8.0
  Using cached psutil-5.8.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
Collecting pycryptodome==3.12.0
  Using cached pycryptodome-3.12.0-cp35-abi3-win_amd64.whl (1.8 MB)
Collecting pygments==2.10.0
  Using cached Pygments-2.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.0 MB)
Collecting pyparsing==3.0.6
  Using cached pyparsing-3.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting pyrsistent==0.18.0
  Using cached pyrsistent-0.18.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
Collecting pytest-forked==1.3.0
  Using cached pytest_forked-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.7 kB)
Collecting regex==2021.11.10
  Using cached regex-2021.11.10.tar.gz (702 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting requests==2.26.0
  Using cached requests-2.26.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting tomli==1.2.2
  Using cached tomli-1.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting typed-ast==1.5.1
  Using cached typed_ast-1.5.1.tar.gz (252 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting typing-extensions==3.10.0.2
  Using cached typing_extensions-3.10.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting urllib3==1.26.7
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting eth-brownie
  Using cached eth_brownie-1.17.1-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
Collecting aiohttp==3.7.4.post0
  Using cached aiohttp-3.7.4.post0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting asttokens==2.0.4
  Using cached asttokens-2.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting async-timeout==3.0.1
  Using cached async_timeout-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting base58==2.1.0
  Using cached base58-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.6 kB)
Collecting black==21.9b0
  Using cached black-21.9b0-py3-none-any.whl (148 kB)
Collecting chardet==4.0.0
  Using cached chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer==2.0.7
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
Collecting cytoolz==0.11.0
  Using cached cytoolz-0.11.0.tar.gz (477 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting hypothesis==6.24.0
  Using cached hypothesis-6.24.0-py3-none-any.whl (381 kB)
Collecting packaging==21.0
  Using cached packaging-21.0-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Collecting prompt-toolkit==3.0.21
  Using cached prompt_toolkit-3.0.21-py3-none-any.whl (374 kB)
Collecting protobuf==3.19.0
  Using cached protobuf-3.19.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (162 kB)
Collecting py==1.10.0
  Using cached py-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting pycryptodome==3.11.0
  Using cached pycryptodome-3.11.0-cp35-abi3-win_amd64.whl (1.8 MB)
Collecting pyparsing==3.0.3
  Using cached pyparsing-3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Collecting regex==2021.10.23
  Using cached regex-2021.10.23.tar.gz (703 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting toolz==0.11.1
  Using cached toolz-0.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (55 kB)
Collecting eth-brownie
  Using cached eth_brownie-1.17.0-py3-none-any.whl (221 kB)
Collecting dataclassy==0.11.0
  Using cached dataclassy-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting hypothesis==6.23.2
  Using cached hypothesis-6.23.2-py3-none-any.whl (381 kB)
Collecting idna==3.2
  Using cached idna-3.2-py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
Collecting prompt-toolkit==3.0.20
  Using cached prompt_toolkit-3.0.20-py3-none-any.whl (370 kB)
Collecting protobuf==3.18.1
  Using cached protobuf-3.18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (174 kB)
Collecting pyparsing==2.4.7
  Using cached pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting regex==2021.10.8
  Using cached regex-2021.10.8.tar.gz (703 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting rlp==1.2.0
  Using cached rlp-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting tomli==1.2.1
  Using cached tomli-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting eth-brownie
  Using cached eth_brownie-1.16.4-py3-none-any.whl (219 kB)
Collecting certifi==2021.5.30
  Using cached certifi-2021.5.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer==2.0.6
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting click==8.0.1
  Using cached click-8.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting dataclassy==0.10.4
  Using cached dataclassy-0.10.4-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting eth-account==0.5.5
  Using cached eth_account-0.5.5-py3-none-any.whl (100 kB)
Collecting hypothesis==6.21.6
  Using cached hypothesis-6.21.6-py3-none-any.whl (381 kB)
Collecting multidict==5.1.0
  Using cached multidict-5.1.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
Collecting platformdirs==2.3.0
  Using cached platformdirs-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting protobuf==3.18.0
  Using cached protobuf-3.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (174 kB)
Collecting py-solc-x==1.1.0
  Using cached py_solc_x-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting pycryptodome==3.10.1
  Using cached pycryptodome-3.10.1-cp35-abi3-win_amd64.whl (1.6 MB)
Collecting regex==2021.8.28
  Using cached regex-2021.8.28-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
Collecting urllib3==1.26.6
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting vyper==0.2.16
  Using cached vyper-0.2.16-py3-none-any.whl (236 kB)
Collecting wcwidth==0.2.5
  Using cached wcwidth-0.2.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
Collecting web3==5.23.1
  Using cached web3-5.23.1-py3-none-any.whl (486 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: websockets==9.1 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from eth-brownie) (9.1)
Collecting wrapt==1.12.1
  Using cached wrapt-1.12.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
Collecting yarl==1.6.3
  Using cached yarl-1.6.3.tar.gz (176 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from click==8.0.1->eth-brownie) (0.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema==3.2.0->eth-brownie) (65.5.0)
Collecting atomicwrites>=1.0
  Using cached atomicwrites-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=223 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from web3==5.23.1->eth-brownie) (305)
WARNING: The candidate selected for download or install is a yanked version: 'protobuf' candidate (version 3.18.0 at https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/4e/9f3cb458266ef5cdeaa1e72a90b9eda100e3d1803cbd7ec02f0846da83c3/protobuf-3.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (from https://pypi.org/simple/protobuf/))
Reason for being yanked: This version claims to support Python 2 but does not
Building wheels for collected packages: yarl
  Building wheel for yarl (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for yarl (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [44 lines of output]
      C:\Users\shark\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-7jfcsmi9\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      **********************
      * Accellerated build *
      **********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\_url.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      running egg_info
      writing yarl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to yarl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to yarl.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to yarl.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.html'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.so'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.pyd'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying yarl\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting_c.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      copying yarl\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\yarl
      building 'yarl._quoting_c' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yarl
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Python311\include -IC:\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcyarl/_quoting_c.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\yarl/_quoting_c.obj
      _quoting_c.c
      yarl/_quoting_c.c(196): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'longintrepr.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for yarl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have already downloaded cytoolz, cython and yarl and attempted to [pip install eth brownie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70027890/error-installing-eth-brownie-with-pipx) but still have this error. I have looked at many stackoverflow reponses to this error but haven't found anything that has resolved my error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to open an issue on eth-brownie github repository, the projects contributors/builders themselves will maybe fix your issue

Comment: I think this one may be better asked in the main StackOverflow? it's python, pip and cython problem on windows

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will do that

Comment: you may search for : "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'longintrepr.h': No such file or directory" questions and look for solution in windows

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, also because I'm going through the same course that you are.  I spent hours trying to get it work with a variety of approaches.

The following worked, and now I have brownie running on my machine:

1. Downgrade Python to v3.9 (there are tutorials on how to do this).
2. Just in case, I installed certain dependencies in advance with these commands --

> python -m pip install yarl

> python -m pip install bitarray

> python -m pip install cytoolz

3. I tried to install brownie with the final command of --

> python -m pip install eth-brownie

4. It failed at first.  I was running all of that from a regular shell.  I tried again with the last command in an administrator shell (just open Powershell as Admin) and it worked.

I tested with "brownie --version" and it says I'm running v1.19.2 which I believe is current.

Good luck!  You may try just downgrading Python to v3.10 instead of 3.9.  I may have gone a little overboard.  I just wanted to be sure I was running a version very well tested.  (I also don't feel like messing with virtual environments right now on the main laptop I'm using for this course.)

[I can give more details about all the different attempts I made before arriving at the solution, if anyone wants.  Fundamentally, I believe eth-brownie isn't ready for Python v3.11 on Windows.]

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try that!

Comment: Downgrading python to 3.10.9 also works